# Wireshark does not decrypt TLS, decrypt tab does not appear

Tags: tls, wireshark

What I did:

Setup the env var "SSLKEYLOGFILE" as "C:\ssl-keys.log" and ensure it is valid.

Enter its path in Wireshark 3 preferences -> protocols -> tls -> pre-master-secret-log filename -> "C:\ssl-keys.log"

This is how the package looks in the debug file:

dissect_ssl enter frame #23 (already visited)
packet_from_server: is from server - FALSE
  conversation = 000001BE07524340, ssl_session = 0000000000000000
  record: offset = 0, reported_length_remaining = 39
dissect_ssl3_record: content_type 23 Application Data

All of them look like that and none of them say "is from server - TRUE" for some reason.

I have watched countless videos and read many tutorials, I still can't get it to work.

The Protocol is TLSv1.2 .

Comment: Can you link to a tutorial you followed? Without the exact steps you have taken (or omitted), it's impossible to help. Further, did you ever set up your RSA key list?

Comment: This is one of the main ones I followed -> https://www.comparitech.com/net-admin/decrypt-ssl-with-wireshark/
I think my specific case might be because I am on an intranet and there are security applications that may influence how the network behaves, maybe the SSL keys output is not helpful as the packets are being encrypted in a different manner. I have no idea what I am talking about, rather taking a wild guess.

Comment: I doubt that one can help here without having access to the specific pcap and the specific key log file. And I very much doubt that your problems are related to internal security appliances since the encryption process works no different than without such appliances - only the endpoint of the encryption is different.

Comment: I will try the same tutorial back at home and come back with results, then I can share the log files too.

Comment: In my case Wireshark shows only packets from/to 127.1 decrypted.